# Vertical align within DIV, with a block element inside the div

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

This has always driven me crazy and never found the right answer.

I want to achieve the following:
http://juicybyte.com/stack-overflow.jpg

Meaning, I want to have an image on a div on the left, and text that nicely vertical-aligns itself depending on how much content there is. Height of the text div can be fixed.

However, everything is no go.

```
<div id="widgetWhite">
<div id="widgetWhiteIcon">
    <a href="#" title="White"><img src="/images/iconWhiteIconTn.png" alt="White Icon" /></a>
</div>
<div id="widgetWhiteContent">
    <p>I would love it if this worked.</p>
    <a href="#">Download PDF</a> 
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#widgetWhiteIcon {
width: 82px;
margin: 0 10px 0 20px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#widgetWhiteContent {
width: 108px;
font: normal normal 11px/14px Arial, sans-serif; 
height: 110px; 
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#widgetWhiteContent a {
color: #f37032;
}
```

Don't really care about IE6.0, but IE7.0 is required unfortunately.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: These days your question can be summarized as - how do I vertical align in IE7? For all other browsers you would use `display: table`. For IE7 follow this guide. http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: Just as a note on the IE7 support - MS has decided to no prompt upgrade users to IE8/9 through the first half of 2012. Depending on your demographic (EU, US) I would expect IE7 support to drop to 1% by midyear. So perhaps IE7 may not be as important as you think. IE7 is five years old now!

Comment: Yeah, I don't really to support it, but my client insists on it even though I've shown them the stats.

Answer (score 3):

Here, I put together a solution for you based on the site I linked. I didn't bother mapping your existing css into it, but I think you will get the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/M3h6v/5/

```
<div class="ie7vert1">
    <a href="#" title="White"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x150" alt="White Icon" /></a>            
    <div class="ie7vert2">
        <div class="ie7vert3">         
            <p>I would love it if this worked.</p>
            <a href="#">Download PDF</a> 
            <br style="clear: both;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.ie7vert1 {
    display: table; 
    #position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.ie7vert2 {
    #position: absolute; 
    #top: 50%;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.ie7vert3 {
    #position: relative; 
    #top: -50%;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

Comment: This works great in every browser except IE7. In IE7 the text goes behind the icon, which is really odd.

Comment: Sorry, I was cleaning up CSS and subsequently broke my code in IE7. Take a look at this please. http://jsfiddle.net/M3h6v/5/

Comment: That worked! What did you do different/what was missing? I was about to give up and go with a table :P

Comment: I had removed the height and width attributes because I wanted the content to dictate the size of the div. But removing the width caused IE7 to collapse the text div completely and thus not display at all.

Answer (score 3):

The `vertical-align` property has two prerequisites for use:

- The elements you are trying to vertically-align must be siblings.
- The elements you are trying to vertically-align must not be block-level elements.

That being said, this is actually quite easy to solve:

```
<div id="widgetWhite">
    <div id="widgetWhiteIcon">
        <a href="#" title="White"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="White Icon" /></a>
    </div><div id="widgetWhiteContent">
        <p>I would love it if this worked.</p>
        <a href="#">Download PDF</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note that the closing div for `#widgetWhiteIcon` and the opening div for `#widgetWhiteContent` are touching: `</div><div id="widgetWhiteContent">`. This allows for you to control the spacing between these two elements, since normally any space between `inline` elements in your markup is shown in the presentation.*

***Edit:** You could equivalently set `font-size: 0` on `#widgetWhite` without worrying about whitespace. `font-size` is inherited in the children elements, so you would need to explicitly set that after, like so: `#widgetWhite { font-size: 0; } #widgetWhite * { font-size: 12px; }`*

CSS:

```
p { margin: 0; }
#widgetWhite > div { 
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
#widgetWhiteContent { margin: 0 0 0 4px; }
#widgetWhiteContent a { 
    margin: 1em 0 0;
    display: block; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/DcWB8/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a fixed height for the wrapper div (div#widgetWhiteContent) first in order for vertical-align to work. To keep everything in div#widgetWhiteContent vertically aligned with div#widgetWhiteIcon, both div's should be at the same height.

So a good solution would be to set a height for the outer div, and then set the height of both child div's to 100%.

Your CSS goes like this

```
<style>
    #widgetWhite {
        height: 110px;
    }

    #widgetWhiteIcon {
        width: 82px;
        margin: 0 10px 0 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #widgetWhiteContent {
        clear: left;
        width: 108px;
        font: normal normal 11px/14px Arial, sans-serif; 
        height: 100%; 
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #widgetWhiteContent a {
        color: #f37032;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why diplay: inline-block doesn't work. I thought I would do that and then do the IE7.0 display: inline-block hack to get it working in IE7.0. But my code doesn't work in any form.